# jQuery callback functions?

Tags: jquery, callback

I can't seem to get this to work: Here's the code:

```
// Clears the default text on click, but restores if nothing is entered
var clearText =  (function(){
    $("input:text").each(function () {

       var default_value = this.value;

       $(this).focus(function(){
               if(this.value == default_value) {
                       this.value = '';
               }
       });

       $(this).blur(function(){
               if(this.value == '') {
                       this.value = default_value;
               }
       });

    });

    $("textarea").each(function () {

       var default_value = this.value;

       $(this).focus(function(){
               if(this.value == default_value) {
                       this.value = '';
               }
       });

       $(this).blur(function(){
               if(this.value == '') {
                       this.value = default_value;
               }
       });

    });

})();


$('html').on('keydown', 'body', function(e){
    if (e.which == 9)
    {
        clearText();
    }
});
```

clearText() is definitely being called at page load, but then it doesn't work as a callback function? I'm not entirely sure why, can anyone help me out?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clearText is undefined, it is not a function. You were calling it as you thought you were defining it. Thats what the () at the end of the function assignment was.

```
var clearText =  function(){
    $("input:text").each(function () {

       var default_value = this.value;

       $(this).focus(function(){
               if(this.value == default_value) {
                       this.value = '';
               }
       });

       $(this).blur(function(){
               if(this.value == '') {
                       this.value = default_value;
               }
       });

    });

    $("textarea").each(function () {

       var default_value = this.value;

       $(this).focus(function(){
               if(this.value == default_value) {
                       this.value = '';
               }
       });

       $(this).blur(function(){
               if(this.value == '') {
                       this.value = default_value;
               }
       });

    });

};
```

Now the function is invokable

Comment: Is there a way I can make it auto-invoke when it's defined, and also make clearText a function?

Comment: Yes there are a couple of ways to do it. But don't, saving one line of code is not worth it being a bit cryptic. Define functions and call them. thats how the human mind works. just add clearText(); right after you define it and everyone will know whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put you functions inside document.ready i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   // Your functions here... 
   $("input:text").each(function(e){
     // code goes here...
   });
});
```

No need to wrap it inside another braces/().

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have said, what I posted above is a snippet of the code, everything is actually inside $(document).ready